# Django makemigrations, 'module' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I was trying to use models and migrations, everything works fine until I try to execute the command: `python manage.py makemigrations`
where it raises the error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

I tried to reinstall Django and create a new venv and change settings on my code editor, basically everything I could find online, yet I'm stuck with this error (full below).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_reso`enter code here`lver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 409, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Emanuele\Desktop\Django_Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'flights.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Emanuele\\Desktop\\Airline\\flights\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: Show us `flights.urls`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `python manage.py makemigrations` (Insert your Django app name)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your **flights** app you have to create a file named **urls.py** if it is there than don't add new one and after that you have to add urlpatterns inside your **urls.py**

add this in your **flights/urls.py**

```
app_name="flights"

urlpatterns = [

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling again I had urlpatters [] instead of urlpatterns = [] and given same error.